# Running Time of Oral Messages Algorithm OM(m) for Byzantine Generals Fault Tolerance

Tags: time-complexity, distributed-systems, byzantine

Let us consider a byzantine generals problem assuming:

- less than 1/3 of generals are traitors
- Oral messages
- No Crypto

One solution is the Oral Message algorithm  OM(m), m being the maximum number of traitors we tolerate.

For n Generals and m = 0, the number of messages sent is in O(n)
For n Genrals and m = 1, we have O(n^2) total messages sent in OM(m) solution
My reading indicates that for m = 2, we have O(n ^3) and for m = 3 O(n^4). Can someone explain to me how we have O(n^3) and O(n^4) for m = 2 and 3 respectively ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could you please add references regarding your "reading"?

Comment: @dkaeae https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~zuyu/files/om_algo.pdf